# How to ignore copying a environment variable file in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, heroku, dockerfile, github-actions

In my Dockerfile I have the following line

`COPY ./packages/myproject/.env ./packages/myproject/.env`

This is to test my docker container locally, however I am using GitHub actions to deploy my project to Heroku (`heroku:container`), my deploy script can be seen [here](https://github.com/pandaniell/akira/blob/master/.github/workflows/deploy.yml), I set up custom env variables in Heroku so my question is, can I ignore copying the .env file in my deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove this line from your `Dockerfile` and when running the container use the `-v` parameter to pass the .env as a volume.

Something like this:

`docker run -v  $PWD/packages/my project/.env ./packages/myproject/.env ... yourcontainer`

Comment: Do you have a example of this flag for this use case?